# How to override uploadTooLarge message for FileUpload by some custom message wicket

Tags: wicket-1.5

I have a page which contains a reusable panel. This panel contains the file upload logic. I have set form.setMaxSize() to 10MB. Is it possible to override the default wicket message and show some custom message?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Form.onFileUploadException`:

```
if (e instanceof SizeLimitExceededException)
{
    // Resource key should be <form-id>.uploadTooLarge to
    // override default message
    final String defaultValue = "Upload must be less than " + getMaxSize();
    String msg = getString(getId() + '.' + UPLOAD_TOO_LARGE_RESOURCE_KEY, Model.ofMap(model), defaultValue);
    error(msg);
}
```